# Rails destroy action doesn't work with button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, destroy, button-to

I am a beginner in Rails and currently I am working on my project.The idea is, that when user buy something for someone, it can create a transaction with informations such us: for who it bought, how much it spent and finally a short description of transaction.
I had created an admin column in database Users and initialized an admin user. I restricted access to index action only for admin - admin works fine.
**I want admin to be able to destroy transactions that are listed in the index view.What I wrote in order to achieve that does not work.**
Here is a screenshot of index view:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK1Rg.png

My code in views/transactions/index

```
<ul>
 <% @transactions.each do |transaction| %>
  <li>
    <%= transaction.user_id %> | 
    <%= transaction.borrower_name %> | 
    <%= transaction.value %>
    <%= button_to "Delete", action: "destroy", method: :delete,
                            params: { transaction: { transaction_id: transaction.id } } %>
  </li>
 <% end %>
</ul>
```

My routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root 'static_pages#home'
get '/about',              to: 'static_pages#about'
get '/help',               to: 'static_pages#help'
get '/contact',            to: 'static_pages#contact'
get '/signup',             to: 'users#new'
get '/login',              to: 'session#new'
post '/login',             to: 'session#create'
delete '/logout',          to: 'session#destroy'
get '/transactions',       to: 'transactions#index'
post '/transactions/new',  to: 'transactions#create'
get '/transactions/new',   to: 'transactions#new'
post '/transactions/:id',  to: 'transactions#edit'
delete '/transactions',    to: 'transactions#destroy'
resources :users
resources :transactions
end
```

My controller

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
  #skip_before_action :is_logged_in?, only: [:index]
  #before index and destroy action run check_admin -> ensure access only for admin user
  before_action :check_admin?, only: [ :index, :destroy ]


  def new
    @transaction = Transaction.new 
  end

  def create
    #current_user
    @transaction = current_user.transactions.build(transaction_params)
    #check if borrower_name exists in db - it must exists to make a transaction
    check = User.find_by(name: params[:transaction][:borrower_name])

    if check != current_user
      @transaction.save
      flash[:success] = "You have made a transaction!"
      redirect_to root_path
    elsif check == current_user
      flash[:danger] = "You try to make a transaction for yourself!"
      render 'transactions/new'
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Something went wrong!Probably, the borrower is not registed."
      render 'transactions/new'
    end  
  end

  def index
    @transactions = Transaction.all 
  end 

  def edit
    #get transactions where current_user borrows money from someone
    @transaction = Transaction.where(id: params[:transaction][:transaction_id])
    if params[:transaction][:active]
    @transaction.update(active: params[:transaction][:active], activated_at: Time.zone.now)
    else 
      @transaction.update(active: params[:transaction][:active])      
    end
    redirect_to transaction_path(current_user)
  end 

  def show 
    #grab the transactions assosiated with the user - 
    #user lends money - passive transactions

    if current_user
      #current_user lends money
      @lend_transaction = current_user.transactions  
      #current_user borrows money 
      @borrow_transaction = Transaction.where(borrower_name: current_user.name)     
    end

  end 


  def destroy 
    @transaction = Transaction.find(params[:transaction][:transaction_id])
    @transaction.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Transaction has been removed!"
    redirect_to transactions_path 

  end 


  private


  def transaction_params
    params.require(:transaction).permit(:borrower_name, :value)
  end 


  def check_admin?
    #check if current_user has admin => true
    redirect_to root_url unless current_user.admin
  end 

end
```

When I click on "Delete" here is what happens in logs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1HU8.png
I get redirected to root_path - weird, look at the create action.
I don't understand why it says "Unpermitted parameter: :transaction_id".
I also don't understand why after I click on "Delete" a flash with message: "You have made a transaction!" occurs.Such flash should occur in create action.
Here is the html:

I would appreciate any help.

Here is a helpers/session_helper code part related with current_user:

```
#method to determine a current user


module SessionHelper
  def current_user
    #if there is a session -> use session hash
    if session[:user_id]
      #nil or equal 
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id]) 
    #if there are cookies -> use cookies to operate log in 
    elsif cookies.encrypted[:user_id]
      #find the user by the encrypted user_id key
      user = User.find_by(id: cookies.encrypted[:user_id])
      #if user exists and the remember token authentication succeed
      #log in and set @current_user to user
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in(user)
        @curent_user = user 
      end 
    end 
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO @L.Wini.

For this particular issue, I'll suggest you couple things:

1. In the `routes` file, you don't need these routes:

```
get '/transactions',       to: 'transactions#index'
post '/transactions/new',  to: 'transactions#create'
get '/transactions/new',   to: 'transactions#new'
post '/transactions/:id',  to: 'transactions#edit'
delete '/transactions',    to: 'transactions#destroy'
```

since you have: `resources :transactions` (this is generating all of them for you).

2. In `index.html.erb` there's no need to use `button_to`:

```
<%= button_to "Delete", action: "destroy", method: :delete,
           params: { transaction: { transaction_id: transaction.id } } %>
```

Instead, you can use `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', transaction, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

3. The `destroy` action will accept `params[:id]` only:

```
def destroy 
  @transaction = Transaction.find(params[:id])
  @transaction.destroy
  flash[:success] = "Transaction has been removed!"
  redirect_to transactions_path
end
```

This should help you solve the delete issue.

`If you're interested in improving the code you have for the other actions, let me know and I'll try to help you out.`

Happy coding!

Reference: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer.What about the controller action destroy.Rails does not know what transaction admin wants to destroy. How should I provide Rails with such information using link_to? By the way: Yes I do not need the routes you pointed with one exception for the post '/transactions/:id',  to: 'transactions#edit'.

Comment: My aplogy @L.Wini, I forgot to include the destroy action in the answer. I edited my answer. Take a look and let me know if it worked and if you have some questions. Thank you

Comment: Still, does not work.Here is the log output Started DELETE "/transactions/1" for ::1 at 2020-07-15 15:53:12 +0200
Processing by TransactionsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>["I deleted the token to fit the error message], "id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 22], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/helpers/session_helper.rb:27:in `current_user'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms | Allocations: 1664)


  
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):

Comment: It looks like the logs are pointing to `app/helpers/session_helper.rb`, line `27`, method `current_user`. I think the issue might be in there, but also, I don't see required login for user inside `transactions_controller.rb` in `before_action`. @L.Wini

Comment: I have just edited my initial post with the code in app/helpers/session_helper.rb